# web Scraping search Results in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am very new to web scraping with Python. In the web page, which I am trying to scrape, I can enter string 'ABC' in the text box and click search. This gives me the details of 'ABC', **but under the same URL**. There is no change in url. I am trying to scrape the result details information.
I have worked till the "search" click. But I do not know how to capture the results of the search (details of search string 'ABC'). Please suggest how could I achieve it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser

new = 2 # open in a new tab, if possible
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Tech-stuffs/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/mdrm/data-dictionary'
browser.get(url)
   
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form0"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/label[2]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='SelectedReportForm']/option[@value='1']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search"]').click()
```

Comment: Why is having the same URL a problem? The data could be dynamically loaded like lots of sites.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) to locate the xpath which entails all of the search results. Then iterate through them using a `for` loop and print each result's text. That should, at the bare minimum, get what you want.

```
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//table//tr')
for result in results:
    print "%s\n" % result.text
```